# Refactoring generics

Tags: java, generics, refactoring

Frankly I am very far from being a generics guru and I have to refactor some code.
I have three subclasses: class **D**, class **R**, and class **S**.
Each of these classes extend class **AbstractA**. 
The goal of the subclasses are quite similar, each has somehow similar code in method **m()**. So I thought it wouldn´t be bad if I could extract method m() from the subclasses and replace it one level up,(into class  AbstractA).

However there is some difference:

**Class D works with:**

```
Map<String, Map<BigInteger, BigInteger>> counts = new HashMap<String, Map<BigInteger,BigInteger>>();
Map<String, Map<BigDecimal, Set<BigInteger>>> sums = new HashMap<String, Map<BigDecimal, Set<BigInteger>>>();
```

**class R works with:**

```
Map<String, Map<String, BigInteger>> counts = new HashMap<String, Map<String,BigInteger>>();
Map<String, Map<BigDecimal, Set<String>>> sums = new HashMap<String, Map<BigDecimal, Set<String>>>();
```

**and class S  works with:**

```
Map<String, Map<BigInteger, BigInteger>> counts = new HashMap<String, Map<BigInteger,BigInteger>>();
Map<String, Map<BigDecimal, BigInteger>> sums = new HashMap<String, Map<BigDecimal, BigInteger>>();
```

Any hint is welcome regarding the possible modifications of the above mentioned generics, which can result a more "generic" version.(which can be moved to class AbstractA and still can be used by the three subclasses.)

Comment: Not sure how you can reconcile `String` with `BitInteger`...

Comment: Maybe a `String` like `473894790327849328490829042`, which can be converted to `BigInteger` ?

Comment: It will be easier to think about this if you show the code for the three implementations of `m()` that you want to replace.

Comment: Keep in mind that if someone wants to add a class Q which has a completely different version of m() this solution would become quite a pain for other programmers.

Comment: @luiges90 I suppose so, but that possibly means that one implementation does some parsing while the other doesn't. This can't be solved with generics only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 class AbstractA<T,U> {
    Map<String, Map<T, BigInteger>> counts = new HashMap<String, Map<T,BigInteger>>();
    Map<String, Map<BigDecimal, U>> sums = new HashMap<String, Map<BigDecimal, U>>();
 }
 class AbstractB<T> extends AbstractA<T, Set<T>> {
 }
 class D extends AbstractB<BigInteger> {
 }
 class R extends AbstractB<String> {
 }
 class S extends AbstractA<BigInteger, BigInteger> {
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You only need two generic parameters:

```
public abstract class AbstractA<K, V> {
    private Map<String, Map<K, BigInteger>> counts = new HashMap<String, Map<K, BigInteger>>();
    private Map<String, Map<BigDecimal, V>> sums = new HashMap<String, Map<BigDecimal, V>>();

    public void m() {
    }
}


public class D extends AbstractA<BigInteger, Set<BigInteger>> {
}

public class R extends AbstractA<String, Set<String>> {
}

public class S extends AbstractA<BigInteger, BigInteger> {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is create some commonality between `String` and `BigInteger` .  My recommendation is to create a new class that is `composed` of these two types:

```
public class Special  
{  
    private String string;  
    private BigInteger bigInt;  
    ...
}
```

Now you can change the parameters of your `Map` like so:

```
Map<String, Map<Special, BigInteger> ...
```

Now you can leave the invocation in each subclass and mark the `m` function in `AbstractA` as either `abstract` or provide an implementation that can be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

What about the following implementation?

```java
public abstract class AbstractA<K1, V1, K2, V2> {

    protected Map<String, Map<K1, V1>> counts;
    protected Map<String, Map<K2, V2>> sums;

    public void m() {
        // your factorized code using counts and sums
    }

}

public class D extends AbstractA<BigInteger, BigInteger, BigDecimal, Set<BigInteger>> {

    public D() {
        counts = new HashMap<String, Map<BigInteger, BigInteger>>();
        sums = new HashMap<String, Map<BigDecimal, Set<BigInteger>>>();
    }

}

public class R extends AbstractA<String, BigInteger, BigDecimal, Set<String>> {

    public R() {
        counts = new HashMap<String, Map<String, BigInteger>>();
        sums = new HashMap<String, Map<BigDecimal, Set<String>>>();
    }

}

public class S extends AbstractA<BigInteger, BigInteger, BigDecimal, BigInteger> {

    public S() {
        counts = new HashMap<String, Map<BigInteger, BigInteger>>();
        sums = new HashMap<String, Map<BigDecimal, BigInteger>>();
    }

}
```